# How to set a custom content type in an Elm HTTP request

Tags: http-headers, elm

I am exploring Elm for use in a single-page application with a REST backend that follows the JSON:API specification. Hence, all resources have the content type `application/vnd.api+json` instead of the usual `application/json`. What is the recommended approach to configure this content type in an Elm SPA?

To my understanding, when I use `Http.expectJson` as expected response type, `elm/http` will automatically set the request header content type to `application/json`. How can I change that? Do I need to write my own request functions that wrap `Http.request`? Is there a simpler, less invasive way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, it sounds like you are trying to set the Content-Type header of the HTTP request that you are sending to your server. The `Http.expectJson` function doesn't modify the request header.

If you wanted to change the request header, you can use `Http.stringBody` to manually set the Content Type being sent to the server. Here's a simple example of such a helper function.

```
postApiJson : String -> (Result Http.Error a -> msg) -> Decoder a -> Json.Encode.Value -> Cmd msg
postApiJson url msg decoder body =
    Http.post
        { url = url
        , expect = Http.expectJson msg decoder
        , body = Http.stringBody "application/vnd.api+json" (Json.Encode.encode 0 body)
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and pointing out that the Expect parameter has no influence on the content type of the request.

Answer (score 2):

The `Content-Type` header is set based on the body, not the expected response (e.g. you could send JSON and expect a byte response, or vice versa). That header is being set to `application/json` when you use `jsonBody`, but you can easily use `stringBody` if you need to use another content type:

```
import Json.Encode as Encode

apiJsonBody : Encode.Value -> Body
apiJsonBody value =
    stringBody "application/vnd.api+json" (Encode.encode 0 value)

postBook : Book -> Cmd Msg
postBook book =
  Http.post
    { url = "https://example.com/books"
    , body = apiJsonBody (encodeBook book)
    , expect = Http.expectJson GotBooks (list string)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Both answers are essentially identical, but I can mark only one as accepted. I randomly picked the one I read first.